# How do i sort files into similar directory structures?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I'm not really too sure how to put this without sounding illiterate, but I'm trying to write a python program that takes a bunch of sorted files, convert them to torrent files, then sort them in a different directory based on the previously converted files. I have some code, and its able to convert all of the files successfully, but i don't know how to implement the sorting portion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

for (dir, _, files) in os.walk("C:\Torrents"):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(dir, f)
        print(path)
        os.system('python py3createtorrent.py "' + path + '"
                  "udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce"')

shutil.rmtree('__pycache__')
```

Here's an example of the directory structure:

[image: screenshot showing directory structure in windows explorer]

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output of the sorted files/directory? Any reason you are calling `os.system('python ...')` instead of just importing it?

Comment: Sorted files?  You mean named with some naming pattern so that they show up in some desired order in a directory listing that sorts by name?

Comment: The input are these folders with rar\zip files in them [link](http://imgur.com/W0MyONT) i want the program to create the torrent file, then be able to put the torrent files in to a different directory with the same corresponding folder, so that it stays sorted. I have renamed each file with a prefix that fits with their folder, ex. DAW_[filename].rar for the files that are in the DAW folder, GAMES_[filename].rar, and so on if that helps with anything.

Comment: That's a lot of information but you still haven't specified _how_ the files should be sorted — what order should they be in regardless of their name(s)?

Comment: @martineau They should be sorted alphabetically by their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is process the files in the source directory in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), this can easily been done by explicitly sorting the list they are in before iterating through it as shown below:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

for (dir, _, files) in os.walk("C:\\Torrents"):  # note double backslashes
    for f in sorted(files):  # note call to sorted() function
        path = os.path.join(dir, f)
        print(path)
        os.system('python py3createtorrent.py "' +
                  path +
                  '" "udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce"')

shutil.rmtree('__pycache__')
```

If the `py3createtorrent.py` script adds the same folder prefix, `'DAW_'` or `'GAMES_'` for example, to all the filenames from the same source subdirectory, they will retain their same relative order with respect to each other in the destination folder.